# MySQL now method vs timestamp

Tags: java, mysql, unix, tomcat, timestamp

I need to keep the connected users synchronized with the changed values in my database. To do that, users send me a `timestamp` and I send back every record where the `changed_time > timestamp`. This should be in database level so I need to use the time from the database. I am calling `SELECT NOW()` SQL to get the time and then read this from the result set and finally attach to the response. Next time client synchronizes, the returned timestamp value will be used.

My question is, should I use `TIMESTAMP` and `now()` method for every incoming synchronization request or keep the value in `UNIX` time as `LONG`? Just to add, testing the performance for about 1,000 clients performing synchronization requests every 10 seconds. Using Tomcat and MySQL.

What's your advice? Is my approach right? How'd you do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can take one more column and assign datatype CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and it will automatically update timestamp while any record update and insert new record. using this you can fetch record on given timestamp by user. Hope it will works for you.